# How to update one field from a passed object in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql

Incase I have an object that looks like the one below

```
const auth = {
        geohash: args.input.geohash,
        offenses: args.input.offenses,
        online: args.input.online,
        paid: args.input.paid,
        profilePic: args.input.profilePic,
        username: args.input.username,
    }
```

and I pass it inorder to update a document

```
const update = { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(args._id) }
    const value = await DiscoverUsers.findOneAndUpdate(update, auth, { useFindAndModify: false, new: true })
```

so incase I only want to update the username and I don't want to keep creating a mutation for updating each field in the document.
lets say my mutation looks like this

```
 mutation{
  updateDiscoverUsers(_id:"5dab7c198a83f235c89a964a",input:{username:"peter"}){
    username
  }
}
```

but this only updates the username but it makes the rest of the fields null but I only want to find a way to only update the fields I have passed in the mutation and the rest remain the same. so I can update the username and profilePic only and the rest remain unchanged.
I would be grateful for the help and thanks in advance

Comment: Does the query make the rest of the fields `null` or `undefined`?

Comment: makes them null

Comment: Have you tried stripping out all the null values in the `auth` object before using it for the update query? For example, if `args.input.paid` is `null` then it should not be added to the auth object. You can use this simple snippet to achieve that:
```
for(let key in auth) {
    if(auth[key] === null) delete auth[key]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the atomic operator `$set` to update only where you want, and you should pass only the fields you want to update, not all of them otherwise all the fields are going to be updated by the new value.

like:

```
const value = await DiscoverUsers.findOneAndUpdate(update, {$set:{username:"pedro"}}, { useFindAndModify: false, new: true })
```

Comment: so I have to create a mutation to update each field separately. ?